# MySQL conditional querying many to many relations (inner joined tables) from an array

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I've a `colors` table and an `items` table, with a **many to many** relation between these 2 tables (via an `items_colors` table). An item can have many colors and a color can have many items.

```
items
   id

colors
   id
   name

items_colors
    item_id [foreign key: items(id)]
    color_id [foreign key: colors(id)]
```

From an array of colors, I would like to get all items that **only match** one or more provided colors. 
If an item is also associated with an additional color that is not specified in the array, it should not be retrieved.

```sql
SELECT
    `*`
FROM
    `items`
    INNER JOIN `items_colors` ON `items_colors`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
    INNER JOIN `colors` ON `colors`.`id` = `items_colors`.`color_id`
WHERE
    `colors`.`name` IN('green', 'blue')
```

In my example above I would like to get **all** items that match the given array, so all items that have *green*, or *blue*, or *green* and *blue* color(s). **But** if an item has the *blue* and also the *red* colors (or only *red*, or no color), it should be excluded from the results.

Currently, I didn't find a proper way to do it. The query in my example above is retrieving more data than I would expect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i JOIN
     items_colors ic
     ON ic.item_id = i.id JOIn
     colors c
     ON c.id = ic.color_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING SUM( c.name NOT IN ('green', 'blue') ) = 0;
```

This doesn't return the colors, but you could return those with `GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)`.

You could also express the `HAVING` clause more positively:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM( c.name IN ('green', 'blue') )
```

That said, it is probably more efficient to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from item_colors ic join
                       colors c
                       on ic.color_id = c.id
                  where ic.item_id = i.id and
                        c.name NOT IN ('green', 'blue')
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's working well with the 2 solutions you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you could use window functions for filtering:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i.*, 
        c.*, 
        ic.*, 
        SUM(c.name NOT IN ('green', 'blue')) OVER(PARTITION BY i.id) cnt 
    FROM items i
    INNER JOIN items_colors ic ON ic.item_id = i.id
    INNER JOIN colors c ON c.id = ic.color_id
) t
WHERE c.name IN ('green', 'blue') and cnt = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I'm running MySQL 8. Your solution looks interesting but I'm getting an error: *Duplicate column name 'created_at'* (I've also the `created/updated_at` columns on my tables). I've replaced `SELECT *` to `SELECT i.*` but it change nothing. I'm a beginner in SQL ;)